# Configuration of web server on mac

Tags: macos, httpserver

I started web server on mac using following command.

`# apachectl start`

But other devices in same private network can not be able to access the http service of my mac pc. Browser was showing`site unreachable`.

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: "I think i have to modify http configuration files".  Nope.

Comment: Droppy, you know solution ?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com